# Bootstrap 3 - Expanding and Collapsing Table Rows

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `table` in a web page with Bootstrap. This `table` has rows that I want to expand/collapse. It is intended to act like a hierarchy. You can see the `table` in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/xNoTTwV8XT). You can see that it successfully expands / collapses the "grandparent" content. However, it doesn't expand/collapse each "parent" element's content as needed.

How do I expand / collapse the child rows in this `table`? Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="list-group-item" id="grandparent">
    <div id="expander" data-target="#grandparentContent" data-toggle="collapse" data-group-id="grandparent" data-role="expander">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li id="grandparentIcon">&gt;</li>
            <li>Grandparent</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="grandparentContent" aria-expanded="true">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr data-toggle="collapse">
            <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
            <td>Parent 1</td>
            <td>04/02/2017</td>
            <td>04/04/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child A</td>
            <td>04/01/2017</td>
            <td>04/05/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child B</td>
            <td>04/03/2017</td>
            <td>04/04/2017</td>
          </tr>          

          <tr data-toggle="collapse">
            <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
            <td>Parent 2</td>
            <td>04/03/2017</td>
            <td>04/10/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child X</td>
            <td>04/10/2017</td>
            <td>04/11/2017</td>
          </tr>          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Parent's don't have a `data-target`. They need one.

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/j7jDkdSrKt)

You must add the `data-target="#collapseContent1" data-toggle="collapse"` attributes to Parent 1 and Parent 2 just like you have done it for Grandparent.

And then give the id to target.

```
<div class="list-group-item" id="grandparent">
    <div id="expander" data-target="#grandparentContent" data-toggle="collapse" data-group-id="grandparent" data-role="expander">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li id="grandparentIcon">&gt;</li>
            <li>Grandparent</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="grandparentContent" aria-expanded="true">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr >
            <td data-target="#collapseContent1" data-toggle="collapse" data-group-id="grandparent" data-role="expander"><div>&gt;</div></td>
            <td>Parent 1</td>
            <td>04/02/2017</td>
            <td>04/04/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse" id="collapseContent1" aria-expanded="true">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child A</td>
            <td>04/01/2017</td>
            <td>04/05/2017</td>
          </tr>               

          <tr>
            <td data-target="#collapseContent2" data-toggle="collapse" data-group-id="grandparent" data-role="expander"><div>&gt;</div></td>
            <td>Parent 2</td>
            <td>04/03/2017</td>
            <td>04/10/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse" id="collapseContent2" aria-expanded="true">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child B</td>
            <td>04/03/2017</td>
            <td>04/04/2017</td>
          </tr>         
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But you won't get animation for tr elements.

This appears to be a longstanding pre-existing issue with animating tr elements - my recommendation is to not do it. But if you are still looking for a workaround here is a demo that might help:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GV9Euz5AJFllik7VhHM5?p=preview)

Comment: I was able to get that far. However, the indicator (> | v) on the parent elements do not toggle like they do on the grandparent element. How do you toggle the icon on the parent elements?

Comment: This appears to be a longstanding pre-existing issue with animating tr elements - my recommendation is to not do it. But if you are still looking for a workaround here is a demo that might help: http://plnkr.co/edit/GV9Euz5AJFllik7VhHM5?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Here is working example with based on classes  [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/blBQH44Z0m)

This will show all matched childs.

Comment: I was able to get that far. However, the indicator (> | v) on the parent elements do not toggle like they do on the grandparent element. How do you toggle the icon on the parent elements?